# RNN and LSTM for discovering time lag

Tags: deep-learning

Is there a good reference / tutorial for using RNN/LSTM to determine lag interval for 2 time series? E.g. I have {x_n}, {y_n} and I want to figure out by how much does {x_n} typically lags behind {y_n}?